# Nested-for-loop is returning a table with wrong repetitive values

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-for-loop

```
glas <- vector()
ess <- vector()
sal <- vector()
deep <- vector()
bdate_group <- vector()
doy_group <- vector()

for (bdate_group_num in 1:8) { #repeats same values for corresponding doy groups within each bdate
  for (doy_group_num in 1:7) {
    
    tot <- sum(ofig$doy_group_num == doy_group_num, na.rm = TRUE)
    
    g <- (sum(ofig$Site == "G" & ofig$doy_group_num == doy_group_num, na.rm = TRUE) / tot) * 67.43
    e <- (sum(ofig$Site == "E" & ofig$doy_group_num == doy_group_num, na.rm = TRUE) / tot) * 10.12
    s <- (sum(ofig$Site == "S" & ofig$doy_group_num == doy_group_num, na.rm = TRUE) / tot) * 16.69
    d <- (sum(ofig$Site == "D" & ofig$doy_group_num == doy_group_num, na.rm = TRUE) / tot) * 10.51
    
    glas <- c(glas, g)
    ess <- c(ess, e)
    sal <- c(sal, s)
    deep <- c(deep, d)
    bdate_group <- c(bdate_group, bdate_group_num)
    doy_group <- c(doy_group, doy_group_num)
  }
}

#create data frame
ofig1 <- data.frame(bdate_group = bdate_group, doy_group = doy_group, glas = glas, ess = ess, sal = sal, deep = deep)

#sum across columns for weighted average
ofig1$wa <- rowSums(ofig1[, c("glas", "ess", "sal", "deep")])
```

I have placed every individual into two groups, a doy group and a bdate group. I wish to get a weighted  average of the individuals found at each location(g,e,s,d) for each doy group within each bdate group. However, something is going wrong with one of the loops as every doy group returns the same exact values.

I am trying to get a 56 row data frame that has the weighted values of each doy/bdate combination for each location as well as the weighted average which would be the sum across all the columns.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your `ofig` - maybe something like `dput(head(ofig[,c("Site","doy_group_num")], 100)`.  At first glance, my guess is you can do this more efficiently than using nested loops

Comment: Sure thing - what other method do you have in mind?  structure(list(Site = c("G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G"), doy_group_num = c(3, 6, 7, 
4, 2, 5, 7, 1, 6, 5, 7, 7, 4, 3, 7), bdate_group_num = c(4, 6, 
NA, 7, 4, 8, 8, 5, 6, 5, 8, NA, 7, 5, 8))

Answer (score 0):

Note that in your original nested loops, you don't use `bdate_group_num`. t in definition of `tot` and in the defintions for `g`, `s`, `e`, and `d` you use `doy_group_num`, whereas in the latter these definitions should use `bdate_group_num`

Implementing that fix may get you want you want.

Here is another approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

cross_join(
  reframe(filter(ofig,!is.na(doy_group_num)), den=n(), .by = c(Site, doy_group_num)) %>%
    group_by(Site) %>%
    complete(doy_group_num=1:7, fill = list(den=0)) %>% 
    ungroup(),
  reframe(filter(ofig,!is.na(bdate_group_num)), num = n(), .by = c(Site, bdate_group_num)) %>% 
    group_by(Site) %>% 
    complete(bdate_group_num=1:8, fill=list(num=0)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(-Site)
) %>% 
  inner_join(data.frame(Site=c("G", "S", "E", "D"), wts = c(67.43, 10.12, 16.69, 10.51)), by="Site") %>% 
  mutate(v = wts*num/den) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(doy_group_num, bdate_group_num), names_from=Site, values_from=v)
```

Output (from Site G data only givin in the comments)

```
   doy_group_num bdate_group_num     G
           <dbl>           <dbl> <dbl>
 1             1               1    0 
 2             1               2    0 
 3             1               3    0 
 4             1               4  135.
 5             1               5  202.
 6             1               6  135.
 7             1               7  135.
 8             1               8  270.
 9             2               1    0 
10             2               2    0 
# … with 46 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```